# How to implement a common HTTP entry point for multiple Mule applications?

Tags: mule

I'm looking for the advise regarding a best practice when implementing a common entry point for multiple HTTP Mule applications. 
Basically, we have a number of Mule applications running on the same Mule runtime that receive HTTP requests. In order to separate them, they are currently configured with listening different port numbers. The requirement is that applications could be re-started/stopped/updated/added without affecting other apps. Now, using a new port per app is obviously not a best practice. I presume, that some common router/listener is required that would route requests to a particular application based on the URL path. So, is there some commonly used design for such the central entry point app? The main problem I could see here is avoiding impact on other apps  when adding a new or updating an existing app's URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to configure the HTTP connector in a domain and make all the applications use an HTTP listener referencing it and listening in a different path.
Take a look at [shared resources documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/shared-resources) or [this blog post](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/optimize-resource-utilization-mule-shared-resources/).

Comment: Could you pls provide some more details? What does it mean " configure the HTTP connector in a domain"? Where to configure it? In a separate new application?

Comment: I added the links to the documentation, let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code if you need :

mule-domain-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<domain:mule-domain
        xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
        xmlns:domain="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/domain"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
        xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/domain http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/domain/current/mule-domain.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">

        <http:listener-config 
            name="shared-http-listener" 
            host="0.0.0.0" port="6541" 
            doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

</domain:mule-domain>
```

And in your **http:listener** use  **shared-http-listener**

```
<flow name="flow_1">
    <http:listener config-ref="shared-http-listener" path=.../>    
    ...
</flow>
```